# Age limit in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to implement the following restriction in PostgreSQL:

> People can not have birth dates where at 01/01/2016 have more than 100 years.

So, I've implement the restriction as:

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_biggerThan100 CHECK(
  (
    (extract(year FROM current_date)  - extract(year FROM birth)) * 365 + 
    (extract(month FROM current_date) - extract(month FROM birth))* 30 +
    (extract(day FROM current_date)   - extract(day FROM birth))
  ) < 36500 --100 years
);
```

Is it possible to implement this restriction in a more elegant way? And how can I compare the birthday with the date 1/1/2016?

My table person has only two attributes: *person_id* (int) as the primary key and *birth* (date).

Comment: That really is application-level logic, and it's also a rather subjective thing. People do routinely live to be > 100 years old much to the consternation of opinionated computer systems like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use functions date_part() and age()

For details, see for documentation of date functions https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_biggerThan100 
CHECK (date_part('year',age(timestamp '2016-01-01',birth))<100)
```

Comment: Thanks. But How can I do to compare it with 1/1/2016 to know if the age until that date is bigger than 100? [question edited]

Comment: Could you use age function to compare two dates- birth and 1/1/2016, then use date_part to check if <100 years? I edited my answer. See linked documentation for deatails of functions used.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is simpler:

```
ALTER TABLE person ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_biggerThan100
    CHECK (birthdate > '2016-01-01' - interval '101 year')
```

The 101 year is because the statement is "more than 100" rather than "100 or more".

Comment: not strictly true. 100 years 1 day is more than 100 years, but less than 101 years. Anyway, idea of using interval is good!

Comment: @BartoszBilicki . . . That is one interpretation.  However, if age is only measured as integers, then 100 is 100 for an entire year, until the person becomes 101.